# How to use _Complex types in CUDAFunctionLoad?

Tags: complex, cudalink, gpu, data-types, cuda

The documentation for `CUDAFunctionLoad` specifies various base datatypes you can use for your function's arguments, including `_Complex`. However, in the abbreviated table showing the corresponding CUDA types only integer (`_Integer`, `"Integer32"` and `"Integer64"`) and real (`_Real`, `"Double"`, `"Float"`) types are mentioned. So what should one use to compile functions having Mathematica complex numbers as arguments? In other words, if I wanted to modify the "addTwo" example in the documentation to take complex-number arguments, what should I change in

```
code = "
__global__ void addTwo(mint * in, mint * out, mint length) {
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (index < length)
        out[index] = in[index] + 2;
}";

cudaFun = CUDAFunctionLoad[code, "addTwo", {{_Integer, _, "Input"}, {_Integer, _, "Output"}, _Integer}, 256]
```

In practice, I need my function to be able to take some `CUDAMemory` resulting from a `CUDAFourier` call and do a simple manipulation with it.